# Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime2 . The incorrect value "1" is supplied in the PIVOT operator

Tags: t-sql, pivot-table

I thought the brackets indicate the header of the pivot table. Can you explain why I am getting a data type error?

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT TLInstance, Data, RPTMth
       FROM dbo.VIEW_MeterData) p 
       PIVOT (max(Data) 
           FOR RPTMth IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
       ) AS MeterDataPivot
```

Comment: We can't explain without some details of the table schema you are using (including data types) and sample data.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/62576)

Answer (score 0):

In View_MeterData I had to add "MONTH" to this code.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT TLInstance, Data, MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, - 1, Timestamp)) AS RPTMth, Timestamp
FROM            dbo.VIEW_TLData
```